# Should I apply for a Schengen business or tourist visa category?

Tags: visas, schengen

Should I apply for a Schengen business or tourism visa for my trip to Italy and other European countries? I am planning to go to Italy for business purposes for six days and then travel in other European countries for the next ten days. What visa category should I choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are not different categories of Schengen short-stay visas -- there's just a single kind, which once issued is valid for both business and tourism purposes.

The visa application form will ask you for the *main purpose(s) of your journey*, and you should answer that truthfully. From your short description it sounds like the business in Italy is your main purpose for traveling -- even if you're choosing to combine it with some touristing when you're in Europe anyway, and even if this incidental touristing will last for more days than your main business purpose.

On the other hand, if going tourist and doing business are equally important for you, simply check both boxes. It does say "purpose(s)", after all.